# UWP CommandBar Binding

Tags: c#, uwp, navigationview, commandbar

is it possible to bind an UWP `CommandBar` to something like a `ObservableCollection` or so?

What i want to achieve ist to bind my `CommandBar` of my `NavigationView` to an Object of a specific `Page` so that the `AppBarButton` change dynamicaly depending on the current `Page`

What i tryed:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
    <NavigationView.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <CommandBar Grid.Column="1"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        DefaultLabelPosition="Right"
                        Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAltHighBrush}"  Content="{Binding Path=Content.AppBarButtonList, ElementName=rootFrame}">
                </CommandBar>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </NavigationView.HeaderTemplate>
```

**SomePage.xaml.cs**

```
    public ObservableCollection<AppBarButton> AppBarButtonList = new ObservableCollection<AppBarButton> {
        new AppBarButton { Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Accept), Label="Bla" },
        new AppBarButton{Icon=new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Add),Label="Add"}
    };
```

But the `CommandBar` shows nothing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

My original solution was using the `PrimaryCommands` property to bind the commands, but it turns out this property is read-only.

My solution to the problem will be using behaviors.

First add a reference to `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed` from NuGet.

Then add the following behavior to your project:

```
public class BindableCommandBarBehavior : Behavior<CommandBar>
{
    public ObservableCollection<AppBarButton> PrimaryCommands
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<AppBarButton>)GetValue(PrimaryCommandsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PrimaryCommandsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PrimaryCommandsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "PrimaryCommands", typeof(ObservableCollection<AppBarButton>), typeof(BindableCommandBarBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<AppBarButton>), UpdateCommands));

    private static void UpdateCommands(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        if (!(dependencyObject is BindableCommandBarBehavior behavior)) return;
        var oldList = dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.OldValue as ObservableCollection<AppBarButton>;
        if (dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.OldValue != null)
        {
            oldList.CollectionChanged -= behavior.PrimaryCommandsCollectionChanged;
        }

        var newList = dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue as ObservableCollection<AppBarButton>;
        if (dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue != null)
        {
            newList.CollectionChanged += behavior.PrimaryCommandsCollectionChanged;
        }
        behavior.UpdatePrimaryCommands();
    }


    private void PrimaryCommandsCollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdatePrimaryCommands();
    }


    private void UpdatePrimaryCommands()
    {
        if (PrimaryCommands != null)
        {
            AssociatedObject.PrimaryCommands.Clear();
            foreach (var command in PrimaryCommands)
            {
                AssociatedObject.PrimaryCommands.Add(command);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        if (PrimaryCommands != null)
        {
            PrimaryCommands.CollectionChanged -= PrimaryCommandsCollectionChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

This behavior essentially creates a fake `PrimaryCommands` property that is bindable and also observes collection changed events. Whenever a change occurs, the commands are rebuilt.

Finally, the problem in your code is that your `AppBarButtonList` is just a field, not a property. Change it like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<AppBarButton> AppBarButtonList { get; } = new ObservableCollection<AppBarButton> {
    new AppBarButton { Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Accept), Label="Bla" },
    new AppBarButton{Icon=new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Add),Label="Add"}
};
```

Notice the `{get ;}` which was added before the assignment operator.

Now you can use the behavior in XAML like this:

```
<CommandBar>
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:BindableCommandBarBehavior PrimaryCommands="{Binding Path=Content.AppBarButtonList, ElementName=rootFrame}" />
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</CommandBar>
```

This is by no means a perfect solution and could be improved upon to allow different collection types binding and more, but it should cover your scenario. An alternative solution would be to implement a custom version of command bar, with new additional dependency property directly on the type, but I used behavior to make it clearer for the user that this is an "added" functionality, not a built-in one.

Comment: Ok could you pleas give me an example how to bind the `PirmaryCommands` of a `CommandBar`?

Comment: I am surprised, but it seems the property cannot be bound to. But I think I am on track to find a solution. I will let you know in an update soon.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution but i'm wondering that it is so complicated to achieve this. Or is my approach to integrate the  `CommandBar` to the `NavigationView` an unusual way to do it? Should i just implement a `CommandBar`for each `Page` that i have?

Comment: The reason is probably that the recommended use case is to create a predefined set of "static" commands, which are declared in XAML, instead of code. Usually the `CommandBar` is in the context of context, so it usually sits "next to" the content, at the same level. In your case you are putting it in header of a container so it is "taken out" of the content itself. In this case it is however logical, because you want the commands to be in the navigation view header, to be contextual to the opened page.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer very helpful. I did some more adjustments, like using a DataTemplateSelector to remove UI references like "AppBarButton" from the bindable data source.

```
public class BindableCommandBarBehavior : Behavior<CommandBar>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PrimaryCommandsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "PrimaryCommands", typeof(object), typeof(BindableCommandBarBehavior),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, UpdateCommands));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateSelectorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ItemTemplateSelector", typeof(DataTemplateSelector), typeof(BindableCommandBarBehavior),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, null));

    public DataTemplateSelector ItemTemplateSelector
    {
        get { return (DataTemplateSelector)GetValue(ItemTemplateSelectorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemTemplateSelectorProperty, value); }
    }

    public object PrimaryCommands
    {
        get { return  GetValue(PrimaryCommandsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PrimaryCommandsProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        if (PrimaryCommands is INotifyCollectionChanged notifyCollectionChanged)
        {
            notifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged -= PrimaryCommandsCollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    private void UpdatePrimaryCommands()
    {
        if (AssociatedObject == null)
            return;

        if (PrimaryCommands == null)
            return;

        AssociatedObject.PrimaryCommands.Clear();

        if (!(PrimaryCommands is IEnumerable enumerable))
        {
            AssociatedObject.PrimaryCommands.Clear();
            return;
        }


        foreach (var command in enumerable)
        {
            var template = ItemTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate(command, AssociatedObject);

            if (!(template?.LoadContent() is FrameworkElement dependencyObject))
                continue;

            dependencyObject.DataContext = command;

            if (dependencyObject is ICommandBarElement icommandBarElement)
                AssociatedObject.PrimaryCommands.Add(icommandBarElement);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        UpdatePrimaryCommands();
    }

    private void PrimaryCommandsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdatePrimaryCommands();
    }

    private static void UpdateCommands(DependencyObject dependencyObject,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        if (!(dependencyObject is BindableCommandBarBehavior behavior)) return;
        if (dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.OldValue is INotifyCollectionChanged oldList)
        {
            oldList.CollectionChanged -= behavior.PrimaryCommandsCollectionChanged;
        }

        if (dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue is INotifyCollectionChanged newList)
        {
            newList.CollectionChanged += behavior.PrimaryCommandsCollectionChanged;
        }

        behavior.UpdatePrimaryCommands();
    }
}
```

The DataTemplateSelector:

```
public class CommandBarMenuItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate CbMenuItemTemplate { get; set; }


    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is ContextAction)
        {
            return CbMenuItemTemplate;
        }

        return base.SelectTemplateCore(item, container);
    }
}
```

Xaml for templates:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="CbMenuItemTemplate">
    <AppBarButton
        Command="{Binding Command}"
        Icon="Add"
        Label="{Binding Text}" />
</DataTemplate>

<viewLogic:CommandBarMenuItemTemplateSelector x:Key="CommandBarMenuItemTemplateSelector" 
                                              CbMenuItemTemplate="{StaticResource CbMenuItemTemplate}" />
```

Usage:

```
  <CommandBar>
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
       <viewLogic:BindableCommandBarBehavior ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CommandBarMenuItemTemplateSelector}" PrimaryCommands="{Binding ContextActions}" />
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
  </CommandBar>
```

Where ContextActions is a ObservableCollection of my class ContextAction.